# invalid statement id received by the sqlexec process

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, connection, informix

I face the following problem during insertion(multiple rows) :(some records were inserted and after a random number of records i get an error) !!

> invalid statement id received by the sqlexec process.

---

```
  public static int InsertGroupDetails(List<GroupDetails> grp_det)
        {

            using (IfxConnection con = new IfxConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["str_rm"].ToString()))
            {
                int affectedRow = -1;
                StringBuilder cmdTxt = new StringBuilder();
                cmdTxt.Append(" INSERT INTO rdm_groupdetails(group_id,dep_code,dep_year,dep_name,boss_num,boss_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) ");
                foreach (GroupDetails grp in grp_det)
                {
                    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        con.Open();
                    }


                    IfxCommand myIfxCmd = new IfxCommand(cmdTxt.ToString(), con);

                    myIfxCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters.Clear();

                    myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("group_id", grp.Group_id);
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("dep_code", grp.Dep_code);
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("dep_year", grp.Dep_year);
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("dep_name", grp.Dep_name);
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("boss_num", grp.Boss_code);
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("boss_name", grp.Boss_name);

                    affectedRow = myIfxCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                }
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
                return affectedRow;
            }

        }
```

Comment: why is this tagged "performance"? "it stops working after a while" is not a "performance" issue

Comment: i want to ask if the number of rows may have an effect because it works for a while then stop !! . if there is some way better than that .or something wrong with this code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely thing is that one of `grp.Group_id`, `grp.Dep_code`, `grp.Dep_year`, `grp.Dep_name`, `grp.Boss_code` or `grp.Boss_name` is `null` for at least one `grp`. Parameter values with a `null` values *are not sent*; you might re-write to:

```
myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("group_id", ((object)grp.Group_id) ?? DBNull.Value);
```

etc (i.e. for each of them); this will pass a database `null` (different to a C# `null`) for any such values.

The second thing I would look to do would be to re-use a single command instance:

```
using(var myIfxCmd = new IfxCommand(cmdTxt.ToString(), con))
{
    myIfxCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    // declare parameters (without values; note you might need to declare types)
    var id = myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("group_id");
    // ... times 6
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    foreach (GroupDetails grp in grp_det)
    {
        // assign parameter values for this iteration
        id.Value = ((object)grp.Group_id) ?? DBNull.Value;
        // ... times 6
        myIfxCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: @just_name so it isn't the `IfxParameter.Value` [shown here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.netpr.doc/netpr59.htm)?

Comment: hmmm:
i did that :
`var id = myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("group_id");` then `id. ...`
i can't find `Value`

Comment: @just_name that is really odd; I don't use the Ifx code, so I can't comment past that - but that is atypical. As a side note: the `Add` will need to be one that the parameter is not the "value". But `IfxParameter` does *claim* to have a `.Value`; [here is is in v11.10, too](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.net_cc.doc/dqx1db2parameterclass.htm)

Comment: to avoid `The IfxParameterCollection only accepts non-null IfxParameter type objects, not String objects`